# Align rotation of an object with first person camera opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I´m trying to implements a bullet so I have this free movement first person camera. I got this camera from learnopengl.com this is the coding:

```
// Default camera values
const float YAW         = -90.0f;
const float PITCH       =  0.0f;
const float SPEED       =  2.5f;
const float SENSITIVITY =  0.1f;
const float ZOOM        =  45.0f;


// An abstract camera class that processes input and calculates the corresponding Euler Angles, Vectors and Matrices for use in OpenGL
class Camera
{
public:
    // Camera Attributes
    glm::vec3 Position;
    glm::vec3 Front;
    glm::vec3 Up;
    glm::vec3 Right;
    glm::vec3 WorldUp;
    // Euler Angles
    float Yaw;
    float Pitch;
    // Camera options
    float MovementSpeed;
    float MouseSensitivity;
    float Zoom;

    // Constructor with vectors
    Camera(glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), float yaw = YAW, float pitch = PITCH) : Front(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), MovementSpeed(SPEED), MouseSensitivity(SENSITIVITY), Zoom(ZOOM)
    {
        Position = position;
        WorldUp = up;
        Yaw = yaw;
        Pitch = pitch;
        updateCameraVectors();
    }
    // Constructor with scalar values
    Camera(float posX, float posY, float posZ, float upX, float upY, float upZ, float yaw, float pitch) : Front(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)), MovementSpeed(SPEED), MouseSensitivity(SENSITIVITY), Zoom(ZOOM)
    {
        Position = glm::vec3(posX, posY, posZ);
        WorldUp = glm::vec3(upX, upY, upZ);
        Yaw = yaw;
        Pitch = pitch;
        updateCameraVectors();
    }

    // Returns the view matrix calculated using Euler Angles and the LookAt Matrix
    glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix()
    {
        return glm::lookAt(Position, Position + Front, Up);
    }

    // Processes input received from any keyboard-like input system. Accepts input parameter in the form of camera defined ENUM (to abstract it from windowing systems)
    void ProcessKeyboard(Camera_Movement direction, float deltaTime)
    {
        float velocity = MovementSpeed * deltaTime;
        if (direction == FORWARD)
            Position += Front * velocity;
        if (direction == BACKWARD)
            Position -= Front * velocity;
        if (direction == LEFT)
            Position -= Right * velocity;
        if (direction == RIGHT)
            Position += Right * velocity;
    }

    // Processes input received from a mouse input system. Expects the offset value in both the x and y direction.
    void ProcessMouseMovement(float xoffset, float yoffset, GLboolean constrainPitch = true)
    {
        xoffset *= MouseSensitivity;
        yoffset *= MouseSensitivity;

        Yaw   += xoffset;
        Pitch += yoffset;

        // Make sure that when pitch is out of bounds, screen doesn't get flipped
        if (constrainPitch)
        {
            if (Pitch > 89.0f)
                Pitch = 89.0f;
            if (Pitch < -89.0f)
                Pitch = -89.0f;
        }

        // Update Front, Right and Up Vectors using the updated Euler angles
        updateCameraVectors();
    }

    // Processes input received from a mouse scroll-wheel event. Only requires input on the vertical wheel-axis
    void ProcessMouseScroll(float yoffset)
    {
        if (Zoom >= 1.0f && Zoom <= 45.0f)
            Zoom -= yoffset;
        if (Zoom <= 1.0f)
            Zoom = 1.0f;
        if (Zoom >= 45.0f)
            Zoom = 45.0f;
    }

private:
    // Calculates the front vector from the Camera's (updated) Euler Angles
    void updateCameraVectors()
    {
        // Calculate the new Front vector
        glm::vec3 front;
        front.x = cos(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
        front.y = sin(glm::radians(Pitch));
        front.z = sin(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
        Front = glm::normalize(front);
        // Also re-calculate the Right and Up vector
        Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Front, WorldUp));  // Normalize the vectors, because their length gets closer to 0 the more you look up or down which results in slower movement.
        Up    = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Right, Front));
    }
};
```

So now I want to create a bullet that starts from

```
    model = glm::translate(model, camara.Position+7.0f*camara.Front);
```

The issue is that as I try to move the camera the object rotates with it which I know why but I don't know how to fix it, I have tried something like this:

```
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(camara.Pitch), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, -glm::radians(camara.Yaw), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

trying to sync the rotations but it's not working.
I want to store the position because then I want the bullets to go straight no matter where I move. Thank you.

1. This is how I always want it to look:

   [image: Initial position without any rotation]
2. This is how it rotates as I move:

   [image: Bad rotating]

Comment: The thing Is i don't want to cancel out the view matrix multiplying by it's inverse because as I shoot I want to be able to move and the bullet no longer follows me and it goes straigth from where I took the shot.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that this would do the trick with the rotation or am I missing something? @NicolBolas

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) ... to avoid Euler angle related headaches like this you can construct the bullet matrix using your camera position and basis vectors directly ...